# How long after querying Freebase with MQL can I use the returned cursor?

Tags: freebase

I am making multiple queries to freebase with the cursor option as described [here](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/mql-overview#querying-with-cursor-paging-results). How long after making a query can I use the cursor returned? Can I change the limit field of the MQL query and still use the same cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no time limit on the cursor, but it is specific to your query, so if you change the query, the cursor will no longer be valid.